# Phone number Entry question

Tags: validation, phone-numbers

We are using 4 fields for phone number entry. We are supposed to support international phone numbers.
Country_code1, Area_code1, Main_Phone,  Extension1

We default and hide the country code field when the selected country is US.
We also have an area code field, a phone number field and an extension field.

We remove any '-' from the phone number field before it is sent to our server so the phone number is formatted like this when it gets to our server:

cc-ac-number-ext , i.e. 1-800-9059912- (blank extension)

Should look like this in our DB:

```
Country_code1, Area_code1, Main_Phone,  Extension1
     1            800       9059912
```

Now, the issue is that a LOT of people are entering the first three digits of their US phone number in the phone number field and apparently tabbing into the extension field and entering the last 4 of their phone number there.

This cause the phone number to be entered into our DB like this:

```
Country_code1, Area_code1, Main_Phone,  Extension1
     1            800       905           9912
```

How would I fix the validation of these in order to also support international phone numbers?

Screenshot of layouts:
[image]

This is how we do it on another one of our sites:
[image]

SO I guess reorganizing the outputs may help somewhat. But client-side validation is still going to be problematic. We currently only test to make sure the number field is populated.

Here is the new planned layout vs. the current layout:
[image]

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your interface? It sounds more like a problem of not clearly labeling fields than a validation problem.

Comment: Re international phone numbers and dashes, see http://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/23176/best-way-to-display-phone-numbers-from-various-countries -- it isn't necessarily straightforward.

Comment: @norabora Added screenshot of UI.

Comment: Do people still have switchboards and extensions? The number of companies in the UK who do not have DDI [direct dial in, where each extension has its own public number] is vanishingly small. Why not just get rid of that field altogether?

Comment: Some PBX (phone) systems in the US offer the caller to enter an extension to be transferred to.

Comment: I work for a large organisation in the UK.  We are reducing the number of DDI numbers we have because they are expensive, so more and more people would have a full phone number, followed by a 4 digit extension.
And those that do have a DDI number, the last 4 digits IS the extension, so I would be quite correct to only put our 2 digit DDI prefix in the phone number field and the last 4 digits of the number in the extension field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would give your user clear visual cues about what belongs in each field:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fTr63a.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

The advantage is that it follows the pattern they are accustomed to but doesn't take up much more space than the current implementation.

Having the last box explicitly labeled as an extension should clear up any ambiguity as to what should be entered there.

Comment: Well, I thought the "visual clues" were pretty evident in our layout.

Comment: I do kind of like this, however.

Comment: I have lots of designs that I still believe are evident but when you see users making the same mistake then they need some help :)

Comment: Agreed and I will make the suggestion to the team.

Comment: See new screenshot added.

Comment: With the second example, do you still have a lot of people entering their number into the extension field?

Comment: I haven't tracked it. That site is similar to a account profile site and they can only modify what they have, not really "create" a new number like on our main site.

Comment: @MB34: The visual clues weren't great in your initial layout, because the labels 'Country Code', 'Area Code', 'Number' and 'Extension' weren't spatially lined up with the input fields.

Comment: @CharlesWesley: In the UI I wouldn't use the terminology "Phone - International" for non-US users. That might be the way the software needs to think about such a user, but it isn't the way the user thinks about themselves. Every user is domestic as far as they're concerned themselves.

Comment: @vincebowdren you make a good point, I was using the same labels as the question but you could definitely look to optimize that as well.

Comment: I added the new proposed layout to the post. I think that may make a difference. We also are looking into omitting the country code and having it auto set from their address country. Is that advisable?  We also are looking into making the field free form and storing only the digits. Have to get approval for that, though.

Comment: Chiming in one year later. The challenge I see with the non-US format is that not all countries have area codes the way we know them, and not all those who do use parentheses to denote them. On many websites addressed to broader European audiences, I've noticed the habit of writing the national trunk digit `0` in parentheses: e.g. `+32 (0) 2 999 99 99`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove static Extension field. Make checkbox 'Ext.' instead and display your Extension field when it's checked.

Comment: Now that's a suggestion we haven't thought of.

Comment: I'd suggest an `[+Ext]` button. Having `[+]` buttons on a form to add new fields is somewhat new , but the relevant audience (phone extensions implies white-collar employees) will have seen such buttons before.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need all those numbers separated? I can understand you may need the country code, but does it really make a difference to know which digits make up the area code and which ones make up the local number? What about people who have only a mobile number and don't have an area code, what should they write there? How will you deal with your already-gathered data when area codes change (e.g. cities grow and what was once part of the area code becomes part of the number)? I am speaking from experience here - my city's area code changed 3 times in the last 20 years.

I would rather ask the user to write their number in freeform, including the country code. Then I would parse the input to separate it into those fields. Parsing is not difficult: Country codes are public information, so you can find the longest matching code from the left of the entered number and separate the input at that point. You will be left with area code + number. Knowing which is the area code and which is the number will only help you if you have the infrastructure to call the user from a local phone. If you don't, there's no point in separating them. If you do, then you will know the area codes for that country already, hence you will be able to parse them just like with the country code.

Comment: I explained it in my question. The storage system is an outdated Oracle DB where we also have a desktop application that handles the numbers. We are leaning towards making it fully free form but I disagree with you about the parsing. You can't assume that a user will enter the numbers as a parser would view it and with the plethora of formats, it would be cumbersome to write a parser. Google's libphonenumber looks like the tool we will be using to do the parsing.

Comment: The only thing I assume is that the meaningful part of a phone number are the digits, and that you ask the user explicitly to give you the full number (i.e. *with* country code). The formatting of the number for display according to country conventions has nothing to do with what that number means, nor with how you save it in the backend. Before parsing, you just remove any non-digit character except a first + from the input. Google's library looks useful, however it does not solve the UX implications of the four boxes.

Comment: I understand that the digits are the only meaningful parts of the number, we only store the digits, not the dashes or any parenthesis. But it DOES matter to storage on the back end if you must parse the number into different fields. Many users may not understand when asking to submit their full number including country code. Some of our users are really not very computer literate; I know it's sad these days.

Comment: This is the most likely option we will pursue. But it must meet approval, first.

Comment: Check this: http://code.google.com/p/libphonenumber/
It is an international phone number parser. 
I think that this (if it works, I don't tested it) fully implements @Erion's idea.

Comment: @Juan I mentioned libphonenumber 4 comments above yours. I do know about that library and will eventually be using it.

Answer (score -1):

As you had given the explanation here, the same you can specify besides the phone number fields so that the user can just have a look and then they can enter the number properly. This is from **UX perspective**.

From **development** perspective what you can do is just tell the users **to enter the number without spaces/dashes** and then the dashes will be added automatically after the fixed number of digits. (As ***Microsoft*** used to do it while entering the Product key in case of Windows Vista/7/8.)

Hope this may help you to get more ideas.

Comment: I don't know, just adding instructions is far from guaranteed to get the users entering data the way you want - you need something more active and subtle like the way you position and label the input fields.

Comment: And the comparison with MS product keys is unhelpful too - they are a fixed format which the UI and software can deal with relatively easily, but phone numbers are notoriously variable from country to country, from local area to local area, and even within an organisation.

Comment: I agree that the clues to entry must be VISUAL as well as in text.